# bwrap: Creating new namespace failed: Operation not permitted on Install GIMP with flatpack on Docker

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, gimp, flatpak

I need to create a docker container with GIMP in headless mode to test my plugins automatically.
I make that container:

```
FROM python:3.8

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y flatpak
RUN flatpak remote-add --user --if-not-exists flathub https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo

RUN flatpak install -y --user https://flathub.org/beta-repo/appstream/org.gimp.GIMP.flatpakref 

CMD flatpak run --command=bash org.gimp.GIMP//beta
```

But when install Gimp I find this error (also if it do not rais exception):

```
bwrap: Creating new namespace failed: Operation not permitted
```

So when I run the container it does not work. The full logs can be founded [here](https://gitlab.com/nicolalandro/gimp-python3-docker/-/blob/main/build.log). What is the problem? Can Flatpack used inside dokcer container? How can I prevent this error?

Comment: Looking at [Flatpak's implementation details](https://docs.flatpak.org/en/latest/under-the-hood.html#underlying-technologies) it seems like it includes its own container runtime; that probably won't work well in a Docker container.  (It _does_ look like it aims to solve the problem of wanting to run software in containers to "not install it on the host", which seems to be a common-but-complex Docker user case.)  Can you use the [Debian `gimp` package](https://packages.debian.org/gimp) via `apt-get install`, instead of bringing Flatpak into it?

Comment: If I install gimp with apt how to specifi `script=bash`? It open Gimp into a shell without a screen and inside it you can use python3 with gimp and all gimp functions.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem. Reading this thread https://github.com/containers/bubblewrap/issues/371 on github gave me some insights. In the end I ended up solving it with a command like:

```
echo 15385 > /proc/sys/user/max_user_namespaces
```

I hope this helps.